# Modifying member values of composite types in an array

Tags: arrays, record, julia

In Julia (0.3.0-rc1), when I `fill` an array with instances of a composite type and update a member of a single instance, all instances in the array get updated. Is this the intended behaviour and, if so, how should I change the value of just a single element in the array?

The code in question:

```
type Foo
    x :: Int
    y :: Int
end

arr = fill(Foo(2, 4), 3)
arr[2].x = 5
```

I expect `[Foo(2, 4), Foo(5, 4), Foo(2, 4)]` but instead I get `[Foo(5, 4), Foo(5, 4), Foo(5, 4)]`. What am I doing wrong? Should I always update the entire element, as in `arr[2] = Foo(5, 4)` (which gives the expected results)? TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created one instance of `Foo` and filled the array with references to this one instance.

You probably want `arr = [Foo(2,4) for i in 1:3]` which will create a new copy of `Foo(2,4)` for every index`.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it.